# Relationship between two measures on the same space using dominated convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, integral-inequality

Suppose that $f\in C^\infty_c (\mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ is a real-valued non-negative measurable function on $\mathbb R$ with compact support³:

$$\mathrm{supp}(f) \subseteq [m,M] \,, \tag1$$

and zeroes only in a set of measure zero.

The above function is measurable with respect to two positive measures $d\mu(\lambda)$ and $d\nu(\lambda)$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that¹ for some positive non-decreasing function $\varphi$ on $\mathbb R,$

$$ \varphi(m) \le \frac{\int_{\mathbb R} d\mu(\lambda)\ f(\lambda)}{\int_{\mathbb R} d\nu(\lambda)\ f(\lambda)} \le \varphi(M) \,. \tag2$$

From this, I would like to prove² that

$$ d\mu(\lambda) = \varphi(\lambda)\ d\nu(\lambda) \,. \tag3$$

If the above is not true in general, it should at least be true¹ for $\varphi(x) = \exp(\beta x)$ for some $\beta \gt 0.$ I would appreciate a proof for this special case at the very least.

Kindly advise.

---

1. Page 36 of [these notes](http://www.math.lmu.de/~cuenin/Part_II.pdf#page=10) on the proof of [the Energy-Entropy-Balance (EEB) inequality](http://www.math.lmu.de/~cuenin/KMS.pdf#page=4) show that eq. (2) follows from the EEB assumption, $$ \mu(f\log\varphi) \ge \mu(f) \log \frac{\mu(f)}{\nu(f)} \tag4$$ $$ \nu(f\log\varphi) \le \nu(f) \log \frac{\mu(f)}{\nu(f)} \tag5$$ where $\varphi(x) \equiv exp(\beta x)$ and $\mu(f) := \int_{\mathbb R} d\mu(\lambda)\ f(\lambda)$ and $\nu(f):= \int_{\mathbb R} d\nu(\lambda)\ f(\lambda)\,.$
2. It has been suggested that a [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) on $f$ and [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) should suffice to prove the above claim. I cannot see how.

---

**EDIT about notation:**

3. I hope it is clear that when I say $\mathrm{supp}(f) \subseteq [m,M] ,$ I mean that $$\inf(\mathrm{supp}(f))\mathrel{\overset{def}{=}} m \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sup(\mathrm{supp}(f)) \mathrel{\overset{def}{=}} M \,. $$

Comment: How can such a thing be true?  Suppose $m=0$ and $M=1$ and $\nu = 2\mu$, so the ratio is $2$.  Let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be distinct non constant functions for which $\phi_i(0)\leq 2 \leq \phi_i(1)$ for both values of $i$.  You want *both* $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ to be the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $d\mu/d\nu$, even though we know the R-N derivative is constant.

Comment: @kimchilover I have corrected a typo. What about now?

Comment: I imagine, $\mu,\nu$ should be positive measures and $f$ non-negative and non-vanishing.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Yes, $f$ is non-negative. I forgot to mention that. I do not see, however, why $f$ should be non-vanishing.

Comment: I still don't understand how you can conclude the formula (3) to be valid for all $\lambda$ in a continuous range from the data supplied in (2), which  boils down to three numbers, $\phi(m)$, $\int f d\mu\,/\,\int f d\nu$, and $\phi(M)$.   Even if you require (2) to hold for all $f$ in some large class I still do not see how a formula for $d\mu/d\nu$ in terms of $\phi$ can arise. Your formulation does not tie the behavior of $\phi$ in the interior of $[m,M]$ to anything else in the problem.

Comment: Let $d\mu = x dx$ and $d\nu = dx$, let $\phi(x)=x^2$, let $[m,M]=[1,2]$. Then your equation (2) is satisfied by all your possible $f$s, because $1\le \int_1^2 x f(x) dx\, / \,\int _1^2 f(x)dx \le 4$, as your (2) requires.  (in fact, the ratio of integrals is contained in $[1,2]$.)  From this you conclude that $xdx = d\mu = \phi(x)d\nu = x^2 d\nu = x^2dx$.  But it isn't!  I suspect you have given a correct proof of a proposition you have not stated in a way I can understand.

Comment: @kimchilover I am sure I have messed up with the statement of all the required assumptions. I was just trying to understand the end of a proof that regarded this conclusion as trivial.

Comment: @J.Rahman I have updated my answer with a complete proof.

Comment: @kimchilover Your example fails because $\varphi(x) = x^2$ is not a positive non-decreasing function. Note that we are talking about a function on the whole of $\mathbb R,$ not just the interval on which $f$ is supported.

Comment: So let $\varphi(t)=(1+|t|)^2$ if $t\ge0$ and $=(1+|t|)^{-2}$ otherwise, let $d\nu=dx$, let $d\mu=4xdx$, let $[m,M]=[1,2]$.  I think these satisfy your newest list of hypotheses.  Then the ratio of the integrals is  contained in $[4,8]$ which is contained in $[4,9]$ so your (2) is satisfied but your (3) is not.  Did you mean to also require (2) holds for all $m<M$, not just a particular pair as you state?

Comment: @kimchilover You should use '@name' otherwise the user won't be notified. Anyway, I think I can answer this. You see for (3) to hold, you require that the compactly supported function used in (2) is arbitrary. So you cannot really fix the support (or equivalently choose a preferred subspace of $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R)$). Let me know if you can cook up an example of $\varphi$ which satisfies (2) for any arbitrary choice of $f$ and yet violates (3).

Comment: @j.rahman, @j.rahman With $d\nu=dx$ and $d\mu = 4xdx$, as in my previous, for any non-negative $f$ the ratio $\int_1^2 f d\mu \,/ \int_1^2 f d\nu$ is contained in $[2,4]$.  (It is the expectation of $4x$ for a certain probability measure supported on $[1,2]$, with density function proportional to $f d\nu$.)  And where did this ``arbitrary choice of $f$'' come from: a new redefinition of the problem?

Comment: @kimchilover I meant '@name' for any person other than the OP (myself). I automatically get notified. I also meant any arbitrary function satisfying whatever I described in the first sentence. I'm not redefining the problem. Check, for example, the first sentence of the answer below. The result depends on the arbitrariness of $f$. I do not understand why you fix the support of $f$. Okay, in your example, perhaps for any positive function supported in $[1,2]$ the condition is met. Sure, but does that mean it would be satisfied for another positive function supported elsewhere for example? Yes?

Comment: Do you have any objection to the proof provided by Meghana? I am not qualified enough to judge the rigour of the proof, but as far as I can tell, it sounds good enough to me. No?

Comment: The original question starts out with ``Suppose that $f$ ... is a ... function...'' but you and Meghana have converted it into something else. You are still not clear about the status of $m$ and $M$.  Do you posit that for all $f$ and $[m,M]$ in a certain class that (2) holds, or just for some? My original comment was meant to elicit clarification on this point. Meghana's proof is probably a correct proof of a still-unstated result,  not of your originally stated problem.

Comment: @kimchilover Ah, I get it now. What is $[m,M]$? You see I have linked the reference below. My mistake was to proceed carelessly thinking that readers would be familiar with the language of the reference. This might seem like a redefinition to you now, but if you read the attached reference, you'll know that $m=\inf(supp(f))$ and $M=\sup(supp(f))$. If this doesn't solve your difficulty, I'd rather you read the attached reference (it's only a few pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Goal:

We will prove that for the finite measures $\mu$ and $\nu,$ $$ \color{darkblue}{\int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d\nu(\lambda)\ f(\lambda) = \int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d\mu(\lambda)\ \frac{1}{\varphi(\lambda)}\ f(\lambda)  \tag{∗}}$$
which is equivalent to (3) because $f$ is arbitrary (cf. [Radon-Nikodym Derivative](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Radon-NikodymDerivative.html)).

---

### Step 1: Bounds on products of compactly supported functions

For a $\varphi$ which is positive and non-decreasing in the interval $[m,M]$ (such as the exponential), we have that $$\forall x \in \mathbb R: \quad \varphi(m) f(x) \le \varphi (x) f(x) \le \varphi(M) f(x) \,. \tag6$$

Choose $\varphi(x) \equiv \exp(\beta x),$ for instance, so that the above reads:

$$ e^{\beta m} f(x) \le e^{\beta x} f(x) \le e^{\beta M} f(x) \,,$$

Or, equivalently, with $w(x):=1/\varphi(x),$ a positive non-increasing function,

$$w(m) f(x) \ge w(x) f(x) \ge w(M) f(x) \,. \tag7$$

Defining the linear functional $\mu(f) := \int_{\mathbb R} \mathrm d\mu(\lambda)\ f(\lambda),$ one rewrites (7) as

$$ w(m) \mu(f) \ge \mu(w f) \ge w(M) \mu(f) \,. \tag8$$

### Step 2: (Pointwise) Partition of Unity

Now, consider a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ with compact support $supp(f_n) \subseteq [m_n, M_n]$ and $\sum_n f_n =1$ pointwise (that is, it is a partition of unity) such that for some $\varepsilon\gt 0,$

$$|w(m_n)-w(M_n)| \lt \varepsilon \,. $$

Thus, $f = \sum_n f f_n$ and $supp (ff_n) \subseteq [m_n, M_n] \subset [m,M]$ for sufficiently small $\varepsilon.$ Moreover,

$$ \nu(f) = \nu(\sum_n ff_n) = \sum_n \nu(ff_n)\,. \tag 9$$

The last equality holds because $f\in C^\infty_c (\mathbb R)$ and so the sum is finite.

Similarly, $\mu(wf) = \sum_n \mu(wff_n)$ and hence,

$$ \color{darkblue}{|\nu(f)-\mu(wf)|} \le \sum_n |\nu(ff_n) -\mu(wff_n)| \tag{10}$$

From (8) one immediately sees that,

$$ -\mu(wff_n) \le -w(M_n) \mu(ff_n)\,, \tag{11} $$

and from (the reciprocal of) (2) one sees that

$$ \nu(ff_n) \le w(m_n) \mu(ff_n) \,. \tag{12}$$

Adding (11) and (12), one gets that

$$ \nu(ff_n) - \mu(wff_n) \le \big(w(m_n) - w(M_n)\big) \mu(f_n) $$
$$ \Rightarrow |\nu(ff_n) - \mu(wff_n)| \lt \varepsilon |\mu(ff_n)| \tag{13}$$

Finally, from (10) one gets:

$$  \color{darkblue}{|\nu(f)-\mu(wf)|} \le \sum_n \varepsilon |\nu(ff_n)| \tag{14}$$

Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, one obtains the desired result $ \color{darkblue}{(∗)}.$ **Note that we only checked the equality of the (finite!) measures on $f\in C^\infty_c (\mathbb R)$ in which case the sum above has a finite number of finite non-zero terms.**

But one can extend this result to the space of all continuous functions which vanish at infinity $C_0 (\mathbb R)$ because the measures are finite and $C^\infty_c (\mathbb R)$ is dense in $C_0 (\mathbb R).$

### $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

### Technical Note:

In order to make sense of the result in $C_0 (\mathbb R),$ we need to make sure that we can sensibly extend our definition of the measures to this set.

It can be shown that the set $\mathfrak B$ of bounded Borel measurable functions is the smallest set $\mathscr F$ such that:

1. $C_0 (\mathbb R) \subseteq \mathscr F,$ and
2. if $(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is uniformly bounded (that is $|F_n(x)| \le M\ \forall x,n$ for some number $M \gt 0$), $F_n \in \mathscr F$ and $F_n \to F$ pointwise, then it follows that $F \in \mathscr F.$

This means that the restriction of a finite Borel measure to $C_0 (\mathbb R)$ determines the measure ***uniquely***: 
In fact, let $F \in \mathscr F$ and $F_n \to F$ as above, then by [dominated convergence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LebesguesDominatedConvergenceTheorem.html) $$\mu(F) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(F_n) \,.$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the result the original poster was hoping for,
with, I hope, more precision and a less rambling proof plan.

**Theorem** Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be continuous and 
increasing.   Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}.$
Suppose that for all non-negative $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ 
the following holds:
$$\varphi(m)\, \nu(f) \le  \mu(f) \le\nu(f)\, \varphi(M)\, $$ 
for all $m$, $M$ for which $\mathrm{supp}(f)\subseteq [m,M]$.

Then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$.
Futher, the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac {d\mu}{d\nu} $ is equal to $\varphi$ except on $\nu$-null sets.

(Here I use the notation $\nu(g)$ to mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g d\nu$, and so on.  And for sets $A$, $\nu(A)$ to mean $\nu(\chi_A)$, where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function (or indicator function) of $A$.)

**Sketch of Proof**

Note that for an interval $I=[a,b]$, the hypotheses of the theorem give us $$\mu(I) \le \nu(I) \,\varphi(b),$$  by applying the dominated convergence theorem to test functions $f_n$ converging to the characteristic function of $I$.  In greater detail: For each $\epsilon>0$ let $f_n \to \chi_I$ for $f_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}),$ with $\mathrm{supp}(f_n)\subset [a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]$.  The hypotheses of the theorem give us $\mu(f_n) \le \nu(f_n) \varphi(b+\epsilon)$. The dominated convergence theorem gives us $\lim_n \mu(f_n) = \mu(\chi_I) = \mu(I)$, and so on.  Thus: $\mu(I)\le \nu(I) \varphi(b+\epsilon)$.  This holds for all $\epsilon>0$ and $\varphi$ is continuous, so finally $\mu(I)\le \nu(I) \varphi(b)$ as claimed.

First,  the argument for absolute continuity:
We need to show that $\nu(A)=0$ implies $\mu(A)=0$.
By $\sigma$-finiteness it suffices to check this for bounded sets 
$A \subseteq [-K,K]$.
Cover $A$ with the union of finitely many intervals, $B = \bigcup I_i \subseteq [-K,K]$, with $\nu(B) = \epsilon$,  for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.
Then $$ \mu(A) \le \mu(B) \le \nu( B)\, \varphi(K) =\epsilon\, \varphi(K). $$ 
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $\mu( A)=0$.

So the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$ exists. Call it $\psi$.   Our task now is to show that $\psi=\varphi$ everywhere except possibly off of a $\nu$ null set. This seems to me a harder task than establishing  $\mu\ll \nu$. Obstacles include: $\nu$ might be  singular measure, $\psi$ is only defined $\nu$-a.e., and $\psi$ might not be continuous. Here is one possible approach.   There is something called the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, discussed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem, and a generalization to arbitrary Borel measures, Lemma 4.1.2  of Ledrappier and Young, 
``The metric entropy of diffeomorphisms, Part I...'', *Annals of Mathematics* 1985, pp 509--539.  (See page 524 for the Lemma.)
It seems to imply that for $\nu$ almost all $a$, the limit
$$\lim_{r\to 0} 
\frac {\int_{a-r}^{a+r} \psi(x) d\nu} {\nu([a-r,a+r])}  = \lim_{r\to0}
\frac {\mu([a-r,a+r])} {\nu([a-r,a+r])}  =
\psi(a).$$
(Notation dictionary:  what we call $\psi$ and $\nu$ corresponds to the paper's $g$ and $\mu$.) For each $r>0$ the ratio is bounded below by $\varphi(a-r)$ and above by $\varphi(a+r)$, and $\varphi$ is continuous, so for almost all $a$, we have $\psi(a)=\varphi(a)$.

**Comment**
Like the other proffered solution, this also uses the dominated convergence theorem and (implicitly) partitions of unity.

Comment: What is the difference between $\mu(f)$ and $\mu(I)$ where $f$ is a meeasurable function and $I$ is an interval? Does the hypothesis of the theorem give the first inequality of your sketch (which I'm having trouble interpreting)? If yes, could you please comment on the equivalence between $\mu(f)$ and $\mu(I)$?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe  I have added detail that I hope answers your question.  The use of notations like $\mu(f)$ and $\mu(I)$ is, I agree, a bit ambiguous, but fairly widespread.